# Problem with gmail spam filters

Tags: gmail

I have recently launched a new website and now I'm having a problem with gmail blocking all email sent from my website. I'm not sending spam, just confirmation emails to the users who post on my website. The emails are specifically blocked because they have html and links (I know because I tried to send plain text emails and they were delivered successfully). Unfortunately, using plain text is not an option for the confirmation emails.

Any suggestions on how to avoid gmail spam filters that blindly block my emails?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no perfect answer to this, but there are some things that can help improve your chances of not getting blocked. I'd start by ensuring you are using DKIM and SPF. If you're not already doing so, relaying via a reputable ISP or other payed smtp relay service (like authsmtp), will go a long way towards relieving the issue. You should also ensure any HTML you create in the mail is valid HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually the email is delivered to gmail. It's only the confirmation emails that don't get delivered because they contain html and links.

Comment: I know you stated that text mails get delivered but HTML don't. But it's not a black and white result. Most spam-filtering uses a scoring system, and typically html mail scores higher than text. But having DKIM and SPF configured should also lower your score, thus increasing your chances allowing your mails through.

Comment: Thanks, I get your point. I use SPF, but not DKIM. But have to say that the email is delivered when I remove the links from the email.